# Testing bimodality of data

Tags: machine-learning, r, python, statistics

I am trying to see if my data is multimodal (in fact, I am more interested in bimodality of the data). I performed dip test and it does evidence against unmodal data. However, I want to see, in particular, if it is bimodal. I believe silver man's test can be used. However, I couldn't find the implementation of it in either r or in python. (The one in R is old and not working with the current version of R). 
Also, assuming that I have a bimodal data and that I am able to get the two components (using mixtools in R), how do I figure out how to find the point of intersection of the two components. For example, here is the histogram (overlaid with its density estimation) of the entire data. [image]

Here are the two components:[image]

I want to get the the x value where the curves intersected. I could have uploaded the data, but the length of the vector is rather long. Any general thought and idea is welcome including the R and/or Python packages are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There has been an answer on this question, please check it :

[Test for bimodal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51062/test-for-bimodal-distribution)